# Fade image out and fade text in on rollover

Tags: html, css, tumblr, fade, rollover

This is the website I'm working on: http://threesamples.tumblr.com

I'm having the most idiotic problem, but nothing I try seems to work, so I figured I'd come here.

I'm working with a Tumblr theme that doesn't have support for captions (except when clicking through to the image post itself).

What I'm trying to do is place the caption text inside a div on the top center of the photo, so that on rollover:
- photo fades out
- text fades in

Here is the CSS I've got so far:

```
article.type_photo .photo-stage {
        background: {color:Photo Background};
        position: absolute;

    }

    article.type_photo .photo-stage:hover {
        background: {color: BackgroundColor};
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: 0.75s;  
        -moz-transition-duration:0.75s; 
        -webkit-transition-duration:0.75s;  
        -o-transition-duration:0.75s;
    }

    article.type_photo .caption-wrap {
        background: transparent;
        width:720px;
        height:300px;
        padding-top:10px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: left;

    }

    article.type_photo .caption {

        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }


    article.type_photo .caption:hover {

    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    font-family:"Open Sans";
    font-size:14px;
    text-align: justify;
    transition: 0.75s;  
    -moz-transition-duration:0.75s; 
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.75s;  
    -o-transition-duration:0.75s;

    }
```

and here is the Tumblr code for dealing with photo posts:

```
{block:Photo}

        <!-- Photo Post -->


        <div class="photo-stage {select:Image Height}">

        <div class="photo-wrap" style="background-image: url('{PhotoURL-HighRes}');">
                {block:IndexPage}
                    <a href="{Permalink}" title="{Title}"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" /></a>

        </div>
                {/block:IndexPage}
                {block:PermalinkPage}
                {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" />{LinkCloseTag}
                {/block:PermalinkPage}

        </div>
        </div>


<div class="caption">
                {block:Caption}
                {Caption} 
                {/block:Caption}
                    {block:Caption Hover}
                    {Caption Hover}
                    {/block:Caption Hover}

</div>

        {/block:Photo}
```

I've managed to get the image to fade out, but cannot for the life of me get the text to fade in. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not an expert but I think your problem is that position is not an animatable property. You need to specify that you only want the transition to apply to the visibility property, like so:

```
transition:visibility 0.75s;
-moz-transition-property:visibility;
-webkit-transition-property:visibility;
-o-transition-property:visibility;
-moz-transition-duration:0.75s; 
-webkit-transition-duration:0.75s;  
-o-transition-duration:0.75s;
```

(Or you should be able to merge it all into one statement for the browser-specific statements, too, but you specifically used transition-duration for those, so I left them that way.)

Source:[Using CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions), [CSS Animated Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)